# Where to put Origin:=65001 in code

Tags: vba, excel

This question is a follow on from a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939045/replace-values-across-all-worksheets-with-new-value/35945208#35945208).

Based on the answer by @Jeeped, it seems that the best way to resolve the issue is to insert this section of code into a macro:

```
Origin:=65001
```

This is in order to force my code to import the files in UTF-8 format.

The issue now arises that I can't work out how or where to insert the code above in my macro. I have the following macro (that I found online - but can't remember where, so can't credit), that imports a large set of files into the workbook, creating spreadsheets for each file.

```
Sub Extractions()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Dim FilesToOpen
Dim x As Integer

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
      (fileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Files (*.*?), *.*?", MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Files to Import")

    If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No Files were selected"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If

    x = 1
    While x <= UBound(FilesToOpen)
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=FilesToOpen(x), Delimiter:=Chr(124)
        Sheets().Move Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets _
          (ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        x = x + 1
    Wend

ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler
    Resume

End Sub
```

Any suggestions on how to get around this issue?

EDIT 1:

Thanks to @Rory for his suggestions. After more investigation, it looks like `Origin:=65001` is not a valid entry in `Workbook.Open`.

As such, I'm wondering is there any way that I can keep the original formatting from the text files, which is set to UTF-8, while I import to MFGI, using the code above?

Comment: You'd add it here: `Workbooks.Open Filename:=FilesToOpen(x), Delimiter:=Chr(124), Origin:=65001`. It looks like you should perhaps be using `Workbooks.OpenText` if the files are text.

Comment: @Rory the file is used to load about 40 different files at the same time. Other methods only open 1 file at a time, and open separate spreadsheets for each file

Comment: `Workbooks.Open` behaves the same way.

Comment: @Rory I tried both the method you suggested, and putting Origin:=65001 before the Delimited:=Chr(124). Both times I got the Message that says "Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks' failed"

Comment: Did you try `Workbooks.OpenText` instead?

Comment: @Rory Not all the file being imported are CSV or text. There are also some .xls and .xlsx files as well, that get imported at the same time

Comment: Then you should test the extension and use whichever method is appropriate.

Comment: Why don't you test the extensions of each file as @Rory says, using `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)` to pick each file name, then open it as the extension requieres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this could give you a hint.

```
Sub Test()
Dim FD As FileDialog
Dim FilesToOpen
Dim e
Dim tmp

Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With FD
    If .Show = -1 Then
    appTGGL bTGGL:=False
        For Each FilesToOpen In .SelectedItems
            tmp = Split(Dir(FilesToOpen), ".")
            Select Case tmp(UBound(tmp)) 'the last
                Case "xlsx"
                    MsgBox "2007"
                    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FilesToOpen
                    Sheets().Move Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
                Case "xlsm"
                    MsgBox "2007M"
                    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FilesToOpen
                    Sheets().Move Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
                Case "xls"
                    MsgBox "2003"
                    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FilesToOpen
                    Sheets().Move Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
                Case "csv"
                    MsgBox "CSV"
                    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FilesToOpen, Delimiter:=Chr(124), Origin:=65001
                    Sheets().Move Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
                Case "txt"
                    MsgBox "TXT"
                    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FilesToOpen, Delimiter:=Chr(124), Origin:=65001
                    Sheets().Move Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
                Case Else
                    MsgBox "NO Ext/Other Ext"
            End Select
        Next FilesToOpen
    appTGGL
    Else
        MsgBox "No Files were selected"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```